# Form needs to be loaded with current user timezone

Tags: java, spring, jsp

```
public CalendarUploadForm form() {

        // use user logic to find users timezone, and set tzid into form
       String tzId = userLogic.getCurrentUser().getTimeZone().getID();

        return new CalendarUploadForm();
    }
```

I am getting current user time zone but when I am going to set into form, I get an error.
I tried to set
`form().setFallBackTimeZoneId(tzId);`
I have set and get method in another class file
I need to assign method to an variable. I dont know how to do it.
Any help. Thanks

Comment: Any one please help with these.

Comment: You only dump a snippet and expect help? How about the error? Also what is this for code serivce, controller? When does it fail rendering the page etc.